# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED Visual studio Android Emulator

Tags: android, apache, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I am having some issues invoking my web api services from my cordova project using javascript. If I run the same application from ripple it works properly. But when I use the visual studio Android emulator I get the error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and I use fiddler to check, I notice that it does not get to the service.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what happened in apache error.log?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your service domain URL to the Content Security Policy (CSP) of your page. For example, if you were accessing data from the yahoo weather service, you'd add "https://query.yahooapis.com" to the page's CSP. The CSP is just a line of HTML that is located inside of the  of the page. It looks like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'
 data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-
inline'; media-src *">
```

Add your service domain URL just after https://ssl.gstatic.com in that line.
So for example, if your service domain URL was "https://query.yahooapis.com", then when you're done, your CSP will look like this:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'
 data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://query.yahooapis.com 'unsafe-eval';
 style-src 'self' unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

By adding your service domain URL to your CSP, you're giving this page permission to get content from that service.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting back late. It still gives me the same error. Meanwhile the url for my service is http://localhost/PillarSalt.Data.Services/odata/. Could this be a reason why ?

Comment: I also tried one more thing. Tried to access the url from the phone's emulator but it aint resolving. and I can ping the address from my pc.